# Solr configuration

Tags: solr

I'm very new with Solr,

And I really want a step by step to have my Solr search result like the google one.

To give you an idea, when you search 'PHP' in http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FindPage , the word 'php' shows up in bold .. This is the same result I want to have.

Showing only a parser even if the pdf is a very huge one.

Comment: I edited your question for clarity. Hope I havent changed the meaning.

Comment: What do you mean by "parser" here?

Comment: What is missing is the results string with additional text that surrounds the search string. For example, at the solr wiki url http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FindPage I type in "php" as a search term and get the result like google one, showing only a part of the doc that have the word "php" with ... in the beginning and the end, and word php in bold. That what i want in my search result

Comment: Can you provide an example of Solrconfig that do this please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use highlighting to show a matching snippet in the results.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters

By default, it will wrap matching words with `<em>` tags, but you can change this by setting the `hl.simple.pre/hl.simple.post` parameters.

Comment: Hi @NickClark, I've set up the snippet to 10 or 20, but i always get all the result and not that a parser of that result like google.

Comment: Can anyone please send me the solrconfig sample on how it should be to have the result like google one. It's important.

Comment: You can't make your results look like Google just by changing your configuration file. Solr is not a front-end search solution. Here is a getting started tutorial that might help you. http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/doc-files/tutorial.html

Comment: Hi Nick, Yes i know, but that's why i was looking for help. Because i couldn't figure out what's the proper config to do.

Comment: There is no "proper config". You need to write code to do this. Here is another getting started guide that will show you how to query and display the results using Solarium and PHP. http://www.solarium-project.org/get-started/basic-usage/

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking at the wrong part of the returned data. Try looking at the 'highlighting' component of the returned data structure (i.e. don't look at the response docs). This should give you the snippets you want.